Error when creating metadata for solana token
When I input metaboss create metadata -a <mint_address> -m <metadata_file> i receive this error.
Error: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1

You might be trying to add metadata but don't have enough lamports to cover the costs.
airdrop yourself some SOL and try again
solana airdrop 5

ref: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/74e25592612871483f39dc441ce836847d95c9ba/token/program/src/error.rs#L22
